# Change root shell without sudo

Tags: debian

I accidentally changed my root shell to use a nonexistent shell, and now the root user crashes when I attempt to log in. Since I do not have *sudo* installed, I can't manually change the shell in etc/passwd. Are there any options in rescue mode that might help me?

Comment: I would Try using a live disc to fix the root shell. This would probably be your best best. Use a Live boot Cd or Usb.

Comment: The live disk worked perfectly. I mounted my drive and used chroot to access it. I was then successfully able to modify the value of the root shell in /etc/passwd from there.

Comment: Glad to have Helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this as the answer to further help those in need.

Use a Live disc in this case any **live disc** will work.

Mount the Drive and use chroot like `@Christoper Simon` stated.

And modify any settings you made that made the Distro Unusable.

Answer (score 0):

First edit `/etc/shells` to include a line that matches the shell you have defined for root, such as

```
/bin/zsh
```

Just having this present seems to be enough to ignore it.

```
su -s '/bin/bash' -c 'vi /etc/passwd'
```

This should hang for a bit while it looks for zsh, then carry on and run bash and execute the command.

Comment: It's seems to incorrectly read the incorrect shell as a part of the command: 'Cannot execute zsh'

Comment: For both of these?  Yes, I see it does still try to invoke the home shell when you su.  Hang on.

Comment: /etc/shells is read only without root permissions

Comment: Course it is. Crap.